# Android - how come sending an Intent to my app stoare crashes?

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
Button give_review = (Button)findViewById(R.id.give_review);   
give_review.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
{  
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {   
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.problemio"));
        startActivity(intent);                
    }
});
```

and for some reason when the button is clicked, the system crashes.

My application url is this: `store/apps/details?id=com.problemio`

and my Class is located in this directory:

```
src/com/problemio/content/MyClassNameActivity
```

What might be causing the crash? I use this code in other parts of my app and it works, albeit the other classes are one directory lower inside the src/com/problemio directory.

Here is the stack trace:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.problemio }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
at com.problemio.content.BusinessIdeasActivity$5.onClick(BusinessIdeasActivity.java:105)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for the suggestions,
Alex

Comment: Well there would not be logcat output I guess because there is no app store url in the simulator...right?

Comment: with the above code url works fine.did you try with device?  pls upload the logcat output.

Comment: I just added the stack trace. It points to line 105 which is the line that has the startActivity(intent);  ..and logCat was empty for this other than the Exception stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no **market** in emulator that what you find an `ActivityNotFoundException` like this:

```
05-07 22:20:46.702: E/AndroidRuntime(580): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.problemio }
05-07 22:20:46.702: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at ...
05-07 22:20:46.702: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  ... 11 more
```

No other `Activity` can handle this intent.

Comment: I am getting this in the live device :)

Comment: did you try my app on your device?